# jQuery height seems wrong

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have to resize images based on their mode (portrait or landscape) on the client.

However, the height jQuery gives me seems wrong.
The images are inside a wrapping DIV which has a max-height and overflow:hidden, but still the reported height seems like it would be height:auto

This is my HTML (example)

```
<div class="fix">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="max">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.fix{
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.max{
    max-height:200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and the JS-code

```
$('.content').each(function(){
   alert($(this).height());
});
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MLa9Z/

Comment: Purposefully defeating the jsfiddle check is against the rules. If the message tells you to add the codes, add some **real** codes. There is a reason why there is such a check. Your question should stand on its own without external resources.

Comment: You can only get image dimensions after the image is loaded -> [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MLa9Z/4/)

Comment: sorry, I didn't know that. I added the whole code in paragraphs so they remain readable

Comment: @adeneo I don't want to read image dimensions but the wrapper size, just as my fiddle shows. The wrapping DIV has a max-height, why does jQuery still report it to be higher?

Comment: The height it's returning is fine... the .content div is in fact 400px... it's just that it gets cropped from its parent. You apply the max-width to the .max but not .content

Comment: you meant height, right? I agree that it's cropped by it's parent though...

Comment: Yes I meant height. Cropped is not the right word since crop suggest that the content overflowing doesn't exist anymore. It's still there, just hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, the divs you are checking are reporting the correct height. Their *parents* are the ones upon which you are setting the limitation.

Think of `overflow: hidden` like a window and not a paint program. If you look out the window, and see part of a tree, the rest of the tree is not 'cropped' or non-existent...you just can't see it. The tree is still [insert number here] feet tall.

Now, if you stick the `max` and `fix` classes onto the `content` divs instead-of/as-well-as their containers, then your code will report the sizes which you think it should be reporting.

Answer (score 1):

The div you are giving a fixed height to has 200px, but the div inside that one (with class content) doesnt. Essentially you are hiding any overflow content, but the size of the content remains the same.

Try inspecting your elements and using the metrics (chrome) or layout (firebug) tab to view real heights.

If you want to resize the image you have to apply the style directly to the image, not the parent element, otherwise you will crop the image instead (using overflow:hidden)

```
.fix img{
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: I know that I will crop the image and that's intended. I did not post the full blown code here but only a part of it to make the problem clearer, seems it didn't work.

Comment: The code is not your problem then, its the actual question "I have to resize images based on their mode (portrait or landscape) on the client." So, do you want to resize the images or crop them? You are already successfully cropping them, so i assumed you wanted to resize them.